# Loaded Ubuntu 12.10 from Disc on a Windows XP Partition and I now can't see the partition to switch to ubuntu

Tags: installation, 12.10, dual-boot

Just loaded Ubuntu 12.10 from a disc to a partition I had created in Windows. Followed all the instructions during install about partitioning the drive etc and got to the end of the install and it wanted to be re-booted to check so turned it off and re-booted but I must be missing something as i can't see any of the Ubuntu partition in windows now so my question is how do I boot in ubuntu ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It is not clear if you installed from within Windows or booted from the disk and installed directly from the disk. Did you turn the computer off by holding the switch or press the restart button on the screen? Please edit your question with the answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to install Ubuntu than to a partition you created inside Windows - because Ubuntu detects unused disk space, the install screen gives you the option to "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows."

If you can boot back into Windows (I assume this is the case because you appear to be unable to boot into Ubuntu), go back to Disk Management and delete the partition you created for Ubuntu, then reboot from your Ubuntu live media and select "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows."